# Is there a way of getting google search results in JSON format?

Tags: javascript, json, search-engine, photo, google-search

I want to have in my JS app, a component that reads a textbox, and suggests appropriate photos,

The way i though of doing it is by searching google photos for that term, and getting the result in a JSON format

e.g an array of links to the photos

Is there a way to achieve this? and if not is there some other method of getting this job done?

Comment: It is against Google's [Webmaster Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/webmaster-guidelines) and [terms of service](https://policies.google.com/terms/archive/20020906?hl=en) to submit programmatic search queries.  Running this code against Google is likely to cause Google to show captcha for searches that do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **scraper** to get the job done but keep in mind that after a number of concurrent requests, Google will show a captcha which will prevent the **scraper** from continuing, unless you give your **scraper** superpower ability to solve different types of captcha.

Comment: FYI it’s __scraper__ not scrapper